# repeat a numpy array x number of times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So lets say I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and another variable that says the number of times I want it repeated, like 3.

My desired result would be:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

I know I could use a loop and `np.concatenate()` to achieve this, but I'm working with very large arrays, and was hoping for a more efficient way to do this because it seems to me that `np.concatenate` with a loop would take quite a long time if I have a large array and need it duplicated a large number of times (this would result in a lot of expensive copies). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should clarify:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
four_list = 4 * lst
print(four_list)

np_arr = np.array(lst)
np_multiplied_arr = 4 * np_arr
print(np_multiplied_arr)

np_four_arr = np.tile(np_arr, 4)
print(np_four_arr)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[ 4  8 12 16]
[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]
```

Note how the code that works to repeat (or tile) a list in Python doesn't work as expected in Numpy, but there is the `.tile()` operation to help out.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but you can do this:

```py
import numpy as np
# Our list
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
# How many times we want to repeat the list
times_to_repeat = 3
# Our final numpy array
my_numpy_array = np.array(my_list*times_to_repeat)
```

Thats what we will get:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

But if your input is in `numpy array` you can do it like that:

```py
import numpy as np
# Our list
my_list = list(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
# How many times we want to repeat the list
times_to_repeat = 3
# Our final numpy array
my_numpy_array = np.array(my_list*times_to_repeat)
```

The output will be the same as above, its a simple workaround

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question how to repeat a numpy array though - since using this solution would require someone who starts with an array instead of a list would first have to turn it into a list.

Comment: @Grismar how about now?

Comment: Now your code does exactly what I said it'd need to do, but that still doesn't answer the question, unless you feel turning an array into a list, multiplying it and turning it back into an array is a better solution that just calling `.tile()` (see my answer) - it does make it explicit, so it's definitely better than before.

Comment: Nice, I didnt know about `tile()` function